How to write one character at a time in a appium python input box?
I'm working on an automation project using Appium with Python for an emulator. In my app (Instagram, in this case), I need to type words into an input box one character at a time, rather than all at once. How can I achieve this?
I've tried using the send_keys function in Appium, but it sends all the characters simultaneously. I'm not an experienced coder, so I would appreciate any guidance or code examples to help me accomplish this.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

first idea: use PyAutoGUI to control keyboard (and mouse) - and use for-loop to send char by char some string.

@furas i've tried pyautogui and it works but i want to do the same in multiple emulators .

and what is the problem with multiple emulators? Better describe all details in question (not in comments). If you want to use with multiple emulators then describe it in question. If you tested other tools then describe it in question. More people may see it so more people may help. And details may help to find solutions.

@furas i found the pyautoGui after i posted , thats why. With multiple emulators running at the same time its not working , i think because it can't write at two different places at the same time .

nobody can write at two different places at the same time - there is always some delay. But usually it is so small then we can't see it. But some programs can't send event to window/program if it is not active (focused) - and it may need to active window before sending char.

you should add all details in question (not in comments), first you should say that you need it to control multiple emulators - it changes situation. You could also describe what emulators you use, how you send chars - it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code. And important is if you change focus (activate window before you send char)
